# Why are we training Segment Embedding in BERT?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp

In BERT we have segment embeddings that are used for "Segment Embeddings with shape (1, n, 768) which are vector representations to help BERT distinguish between paired input sequences."

Yes, but why. There are just 2 sentences, why are we making it so complicated and using 768-sized vector representation for 0 or 1? And we are adding them to the token and positional embeddings.

So it will be like :

Segment Embeddings:
`[0.321,0.231,...,0.434,0.312,0.123]`

Position Embeddings:
`[0.123,0.6435,...,0.231,0.121,0.321]`

Even If we sum those embeddings, summation will be like any embedding. How this summation will make model distinguish between paired input sequences?

Comment: It just gives the network an extra degree of liberty to distinguish the two segments (apart from the `[SEP]` token in between). This is just a design decision by the authors, probably because they found out that it worked better with the segment embeddings than without them.

Comment: @noe thank you so much, what do you think if i freeze that layer while i am training for next sentence prediction?

Comment: I think that this kind of question can only be answered by actually performing the experiments and evaluating the different outcomes.